# auto insert logged user id to the table

Tags: laravel-8, voyager

This is question about Laravel voyager (I tried to google it but found nothing)

in BREAD I could add relationship so product belongs to user, when user want to make new product he must choose user from the list.. instead of that I want to add user id automatically couldn't figure  how
thanks in advance

[image: an image shows the bread relation to clear the idea]